# C# Cache expire from config

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

i have few application that use the same code 
i want some of the application will save the cache for diffrence expiration time.
there is away that ill call insert cache and the time will be from the config time
call this 
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert
and value will be auto from config

i know i can use appsetting but there is better way?

```
<add key="timeTolive" value="5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly then in `Application_Start` within `Global.asax` you could use this:

```
Context.Cache.Insert("tome", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tome"], null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
```

Comment: i add mistake its suppose to be time not tome and i want to set the time for cache in the config but i wonder if there is better way to set the default time for cache

Answer (score 1):

It, at least partially, depends on the cache you are using. For example, the MemoryCache object will allow you to set the defaults on how long an item has to live. This is not automagic, but you can set it up rather easily.

If this is not an option for you, you can explicitly set the cache timeout yourself when you put an object in cache. Encapsualte this in its own class for reuse and you are rolling.

And, you can mix the two concepts, if you want a default time, but occasionally an object that spends more or less time in cache.